# Strange setTimeout clearing behaviour with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to set a timeout on each request that is sent and work out if one is taking "too long". I'm watching the network tab and each request is well under 300ms, however 'too long' gets logged 6 times! (the number of requests I'm sending). Is there something I'm doing wrong with variables, setTimeouts or something?

```
var ajaxMonitor = {};

function timingStart() {
    var url = arguments[2].url;
    ajaxMonitor[url] = {};
    ajaxMonitor[url].timer = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('too long');
    }, 300);
}

function timingEnd() {
    var url = arguments[2].url;
    clearTimeout(ajaxMonitor[url].timer);
}

$(document).ajaxSend(timingStart);
$(document).ajaxComplete(timingEnd);
```

Comment: Try logging the url with your "too long" message and in the `timingEnd` function. That may give you a little more info to debug.

Comment: Is there any chance you're doing an AJAX request to the same URL more than once? Because if you are, only the most recent `setTimeout` for that URL will get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment it might be because you are calling the same url multiple times. If that is the case, one way to fix that problem is to clear the interval before setting it:

```
function timingStart() {
  var url = arguments[2].url;
  clear(url);
  ajaxMonitor[url] = {};
  ajaxMonitor[url].timer = setTimeout(function () {
     console.log('too long');
  }, 300);
}

function timingEnd() {
  var url = arguments[2].url;
  clear(url);
}

function clear(url) {
  if(ajaxMonitor[url])
    clearTimeout(ajaxMonitor[url].timer);
}

$(document).ajaxSend(timingStart);
$(document).ajaxComplete(timingEnd);
```